# Find server response time in PHP

Tags: php, curl, server, httpresponse

I am using the following code to find the server response time.

```
<?php
// check responsetime for a webbserver
function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    // supress error messages with @
    $file      = @fsockopen($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file){
        $status = -1;  // Site is down
    }
    else{
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}
?>
```

I tested some websites using this code, and it returns that server response time is around 40 to 120 milliseconds. But when i open these sites its taking me around 2-4 seconds to get the first byte.

The server response time calculated by https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ is also almost 2-4 seconds. So whats wrong with that code?

Comment: I think that your code only keeps the time required for the connection to be made; *not* the time required for the first byte of the response to be received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make no HTTP request to the server, but open a socket. What you are measuring here is not a server response time but a connection time.

You can try to load a page to get total connection, response, and data transfer time, e.g.:

```
file_get_contents("http://$domain/")
```

To retrieve header only:

```
get_headers("http://$domain/")
```

Or you can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for even more control.

Comment: Ok. But how can I find the time to receive the first byte? The above method you posted also takes time required to download that html code

Comment: Quite tricky. Server send responses in tcp packets, not individual bytes, so you probably can calculate time between request's 'ack' and first packet of response, but it is quite low level for PHP. What you can practically do is to fetch HTTP headers, which are likely to fit into single window, but it this case you change the request from `GET` to `HEAD`. I have updated answer with an example.

Comment: thanks.. So I will calculate the time required for that. Great!